# How can I set visibility for different groups in TiddlyWiki?

Tags: wiki, tiddlywiki, tiddlywiki5

I want to use TiddlyWiki to share knowledge. Before publishing them, I hope only some users can view them, some can edit them, while others can not get any relevant contents. Of course the administrator can assign the privilege level of the raw contents. 
Can TiddlyWiki or any plugin do this?

Comment: How are you sharing your TiddlyWiki?  Just putting your `tiddlywiki.html` on a web server?  Running the node server?  Via tiddlyspot.com?

Comment: I use Node to start the node.js version of TiddlyWiki server. I have my own web server and domain.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* the node server for TW5 doesn't support multiple users.  You could probably control access / no access by proxying node behind nginx and using http authentication, but I'm not aware of any way to let some users edit certain tiddlers while those same tiddlers are read-only for other users.

This type of multi-user stuff is what tiddlyspace is good for.  Maybe that's the way forward.

https://github.com/TiddlySpace/tiddlyspace

Alternatively, maybe you can re-consider your trust model – if you're doing regular backups, maybe it's not that big a risk to give your editing users all edit powers over the whole wiki, and trust them to do the right thing.

Then your other users can have read-only access, and maybe you have something acceptable without too much mucking about.